# How do I iterate through a list simultaneously?

Tags: python

I have a sample which gives values in the form
[p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p12 p13 p14 p15 p16]

`print(sample)`

```
    [[ 1.43945312  4.29003906  9.55566406 ... 61.11035156 66.15917969
      69.03417969]
     [ 2.98242188  4.29003906  9.55566406 ... 61.11035156 66.15917969
      69.03417969]
     [ 1.43945312  6.17675781  9.55566406 ... 61.11035156 66.15917969
      69.03417969]
     ...
     [ 1.92480469  5.76220703  9.69482422 ... 61.23486328 66.62939453
      69.31982422]
     [ 1.92480469  5.76220703  9.69482422 ... 61.23486328 65.97900391
      68.15966797]
     [ 1.78027344  4.68701172 10.25439453 ... 62.68505859 66.62939453
      68.15966797]]
```

I want to iterate through this sample using a function which takes 16 inputs and gives one value as an output.

How can I do this?
For example, take the function model(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, .... p16) which requires 16 inputs
I want to iterate through the sample such that it will do

`model(1.43945312,  4.29003906,  9.55566406, ... 61.11035156, 66.15917969, 69.03417969)`

(Which is the first sample) and then save the output

and then it will move onto the second sample and do

`model(2.98242188,  4.29003906,  9.55566406, ... 61.11035156, 66.15917969, 69.03417969)`

and save the output.. so on so forth.

Does this make sense? Apologies as I am new to Python and do not know the exact terminology yet
How can I do this

Comment: `model(*sample[0])`?

Comment: Hi, use double `for loop`, the data shown is a list of list, which means first you iterate over the first list, and then in the second list you get all the data.

Comment: the first answer is more elegant but not friendly to some one new to python.

Comment: @WiLL_K - It isn't an answer, its a comment since I can't work out what the op is trying to do exactly. If your comment was supposed to be an answer then you should do so in the answer section below

Comment: @Sayse the question mark at the end suggested that you are trying to ask user if that's what they are trying to do. Sorry if I mistook it for an answer

Comment: Don't forget to read [What should I do when someone answered my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ! ;)

Comment: @Sayse Not sure what you are asking for but yes essentially i would like the function `model` to first take `sample[0]` as its first 16 inputs, save this and then move to `sample[1]` as second set of 16 inputs, `sample[2]` as third, etc, but I am unsure how to write this as an iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for loop and iterable unpacking:

```
def model(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16):
    pass # do something

output = []
for sample in data: # iterate over samples
    print(len(sample))
    result = model(*sample)
    output.append(result)
```

Comment: I unfortunately get an error when I do this, seems to be the problem I was encountering before... I am trying to do a sensitivity analysis
`TypeError: model() takes 16 positional arguments but 1800 were given`

Comment: I added a debug print to my code; can you please rerun the code and add the output to your question ? Leave me a comment when done

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Programmer works fine
One think that you might want to use, is *args in function declaration.
This enables you to have variable amount of arguments and refer them as a list so you don't need to specify all 16 arguments.

```py
def method(*args):
    p1 = args[0]
    ...
    p16 = args[15]
   # Or whatever you want to do with them.
```

However this could lead to `IndexError` if you don't supply the method with enough arguments. It depends on what you want to do with your function.